# parse.com invalid type for key, expected map, but got array

Tags: ios, parse-platform

i am newbie in Parse.in my Parse Table One Table Contain `Location` column and its type is `object` like as it is Shown in to Image.

[image]

Here i save An Array Value in to this Column like as

```
NSDictionary *firstJsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         @"10.010490", @"latitude",
                                         @"76.360779", @"longitude",
                                         nil];
    NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:firstJsonDictionary];
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
gameScore[@"Location"]=arr;
[gameScore saveInBackground];
```

Then it Give me Error like as
`invalid type for key Location, expected map, but got array (Code: 111, Version: 1.6.2)`.

Please Give me Solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use object type? You should use GeoPoint.

if you wont to set NSArray than parse Datatype is **Array not Object**

[image]

```
//Set Value
    PFObject * objLocationClass=[PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Class_Location"];

    PFGeoPoint * geoPoint=[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    [objLocation setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"location"];
//Get Value
    PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = (PFGeoPoint *)[objLocation valueForKey:@"location"];
    //userGeoPoint.latitude or userGeoPoint.longitude
```

Comment: But here my Column Type `Object` is Predefined and i have not edit to this.

Comment: you can try gameScore[@"Location"]=firstJsonDictionary;, it may be work